# How to use promises in functions that can be called in various orders?

Tags: javascript, promise

My goal is pretty simple. I have a bunch of async utility functions that are called in various orders.

Right not it's like this:

`doSomething(doNextThing(doFinalThing));`

But it's becoming unwieldy. My goal is to have a syntax like this:

`doSomething.then(doNextThing).then(doFinalThing)`

but with the ability for the order to change:

`doNextThing.then(doSomething).then(doFinalThing)`

How would I go about implementing these functions so that they are all promise-aware?

Comment: Create an object with all of the methods and properties you need, and return it on every function.

Comment: That will just work.  Do the functions take parameters?

Comment: @SLaks Yes. Wrapping in an anonymous function should take care of parameter passing though, right?

Answer (score 1):

Each function needs to return a promise that completes when its async task is complete.  Check out one of the many existing promise libraries.  An excellent one is [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Then you'll call the functions in sequence, like this:

```
var promiseForFinalResult = doSomething().then(doNextThing).then(doFinalThing);
```

that assumes that each function takes only one argument--the result of the previous function.

---

Using "Q" the implementation of `doSomething()` might look somthing like this:

```
function doSomething() {
   var D = Q.defer();
   kickOffSomeAsyncTask(function(err, result) {
       // this callback gets called when the async task is complete
       if(err) {  
           D.fail(err); 
           return;
       }
       D.resolve(result);
   });
   return D.promise;
}
```

Have a look at the docs for "Q".  The docs for `Q.defer` are [located here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds), but you might want to read some of the preceding stuff before diving directly into deferreds.

Comment: And what if one of those functions needs to call another async function and continue resolving its parent promise chain when that async task is completed?

Comment: @JonathanDumaine I've edited the answer to include an example implementation of the function `doSomething`.  The key is that, while the promise is returned synchronously, it is *resolved* asynchronously.  `Deferred` provides the means to bridge the gap between promise-oriented code, and "plain old async code" that uses regular callbacks, instead of promises.  Have a look at the docs and tutorials associated with Q.  It's worth taking some time to read and understand before diving in too far with promises.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you do in this sort of situation is abstract the parts that vary into variables or function parameters:

```
function chainStuff(first, second, third){
   return first.then(second).then(thrid)
}
```

You can then choose at runtime what callbacks you bind to each parameter (first, second, third)

```
if(condition){
    return chainStuff(doSomething, doNextThing, doFinalThing)
}else{
    return chainStuff(doNextThing, doSomething, doFinalThing)
}
```